# how to copy jars from WEB-INF/lib to another folder in war in maven

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3

i generate a WAR file which has a jar named xyz.jar inside its WEB-INF/lib folder . This jar is generated during build as a dependency. Now i need to copy this jar into a folder say abc inside the war . How can i achieve this? I tried using copy-resources of maven-resources-plugin but it doesn't seem to work as the copying will be done before war is built . but this jar is generated only during build process.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the maven-dependency-plugin to independently put it where you want it.

Comment: thanks bmargulies..i used this plugin with prepare-package phase and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to change when the plugin executes by binding the plugin execution to a different [lifecycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). Here is a snippet to give you the idea.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resource-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>phaseName</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: i had tried with prepare-package phase but it says phase not found

Comment: Maybe try a different phase. Even an incorrect one like test, as long as it happens at the appropriate time.